# display list of dates by giving start and end date and get data against those dates

Tags: sql

I have a sql table having three columns

id, balance, datetime
i want to get data from the table by giving time duration. suppose i want to get data between 1/1/2013 to 1/15/2013. data is given table is shown as:

```
#id   Datetime  Balance #
1     1/1/2013   1500
2     1/2/2013   2000
3     1/4/2013   1500
4     1/5/2013   2500
```

now I want the output as

```
#id  Datetime  Balance #
1    1/1/2013   1500
2    1/2/2013   2000
3    1/3/2013    0
4    1/4/2013   1500
5    1/5/2013   2500
```

i want to display all the dates and if there is no balance against the date. it shows O or null value

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of ID column as it is useless when you are adding additional rows and do something like this:

```
set dateformat mdy 

declare @tmpTable table (dates date)

declare @startDate date = '1/1/2013'
declare @endDate date = '1/15/2013'

while @startDate <= @endDate
begin
    insert into @tmpTable (dates) values (@startDate)
    set @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDate)
end

select tmp.dates, yourtable.balance 
from @tmpTable as tmp
left outer join yourTable on yourTable.[Datetime] = tmp.dates
where yourtable.[Datetime] between @startDate and @endDate
```

Comment: that gives me only data that is matched with the dates. i want all dates that are coming within the range for example if im giving range of 1/1/2013 to 1/5/2013. all the dates should be display either they are present in the datetime column or not

Comment: its giving error must declare the variables. and they are already declared than why is giving the error?

Comment: Make sure you are executing the whole code with `declare` lines included. And don't forget to replace `yourTable` with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what flavor of SQL you're using but you can a table of all dates and to do an outer join to it.  For example, if you have a table of all dates called 'Dates', then you could do:

select id, dateTime, balance from table1 t RIGHT JOIN Dates d on t.dateTime = d.dateTime 
where t.dateTime BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/5/2013'

Comment: no i dont have another column of dates. i want to get list of dates when two dates are given and then display this data against those dates

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a cte with the dates between your daterange and outer joining it with your table.

```
with cte as
 (
 select start_date dt
 union all
 select dateadd(dd,1,dt) from cte where dt < end_date
)
select id, cte.dt, balance from cte left outer join yourtable b on cte.dt = b.date;
```

Comment: but i dont have any start_date and end_date coloumn

Comment: You specified "suppose i want to get data between 1/1/2013 to 1/15/2013". Here 1/1/2013 is start_date and other is end.

Comment: yes but both dates are coming from only one column. DateTime column

Comment: If you dont have this range and if you consider mindate and maxdate of you table then use that in place of start and end.

Comment: i want to pass paramaeters for start date and end date. please tell me how to pass parameters in this query

Comment: In place of start_date and end_date, use your variables.

Comment: it gives me error types does not match between the anchor and the recursive part in column dt of recursive query cte

Comment: See this example. It should work, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc46a/15.     May be you are not passing date datatype to the variable. make sure you pass a date datatype

Comment: The link is not working.. cant i use loop to fix my issue? can u please share another method? im helpless to make query

Comment: The link works, you just have to wait for sometime till it loads. And you can use loop also, but its better to do it with query.